# How to infrom when javascript function was run previous time

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I'm building a PhoneGap Mobile application where I get data from a server with `getJSON` every three minutes. Because it will be a mobile app, the connection won't be guaranteed all the time so I would like to inform the user when was the last time that the `getJSON` function was successful, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it possible to set a global or localstorage variable with the current datetime from within the success callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to print to the screen every time the method is successful in the success callback of `getJSON`, something like this perhaps:

```
$.getJSON('some/url',function(data){
    $('#span').text('The server was successfully queried last at ' + new Date());
});
```

Another approach would be to save the current time in the success block and then if there is an error in the `getJSON` call, alert the user that the last time `getJSON` succeeded was at that previously stored value. Something like this:

```
var last;
$.getJSON('some/url',function(data){
   last = new Date();
}).error(function(){
   $('#span').text('The server was last successfully queried last at ' + last);
});
```

This should give you the general idea of two ways to solve this problem.

**UPDATE**
Searching around I found [this article](http://zeroedandnoughted.com/defensive-ajax-and-ajax-retries-in-jquery/) about defensive AJAX calls that you could try as well.

Comment: You could also store each `last` in an array and perhaps do something more creative such as `if successfully returned try again in 30 seconds/1 minute`  if Fails 3 times in a row change duration to 3 minutes. If fails 3 times in a row change duration to 5 minutes.  If succeeds at any time change duration to 30 sec/1mint.. etc

Comment: That's an even better idea, but I think that is a little outside the scope of the posters original question.

Comment: That's why I +1'd your answer and posted it as a comment!